# Background idea for displaying black png images

Tags: transparency, png, background, black

I need a good way to display black png images in my webapp

[image]

Hover

[image]

I thought about using a "transparency tile" but that wouldn't look good
I even used CSS stripes but the result wasn't great

[image]

I need a background which could work for all sorts of images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a **Security pattern**

[image: Security Pattern]

[image: Security Pattern]

<sub>Google search [security pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=bill%20security%20pattern&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CdoN_1SD2Z3r2IjjK-On3tP_1RfEi9mlvqFUO_1eKbmMvl-zWi1eSlP5yEl9yT_1Sb-JTZlhFS6b6hSswMmpZHBLx14OsSoSCcr46fe0_19F8ET14JdbDYjS2KhIJSL2aW-oVQ78RpzxIhypPHZsqEgl4puYy-X7NaBGQfrYm2R2S4SoSCbV5KU_1nISX3EVXfOuWJWoMcKhIJJP9Jv4lNmWERfl92I7PWQGcqEgkVLpvqFKzAyRH2swrB-GRErSoSCalkcEvHXg6xEdrNpk0f-CA3&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJtaSi1YvgAhUOfxoKHWa9AoEQ9C96BAgBEBs&biw=1533&bih=1200&dpr=1)</sub>

---

Or a fake **Hologram Security Pattern**

[image: hologram]

[image: hologram]

<sub>Google search [Hologram security pattern](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=gW1MXNiTFoi8UvLOjuAP&q=holograme%20security%20pattern&oq=holograme%20security%20pattern&gs_l=img.3...73662.75134..75381...0.0..0.70.593.9......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30.gtaA9Vnu36g#imgrc=_)</sub>

Comment: Great idea, it works for me!

Comment: Nice answer - me I would've said "a typical alpha transparency grid as seen in almost every image editor and graphic design software on the market" - but I think this is a better answer!